# Выбор кроссплатформенного мобильного движка для игр

Tags: unity3d, android, разработка-игр, coronasdk, ios

**Цель**: разработка кросплатформенных игр на мобильные телефоны.
**Основной target**: iOS (iPhone/iPad) и Android, большим плюсом будет поддержка Windows Phone 7, Symbian, Bada.

**Задача**: максимально быстрая и удобная разработка игр, цена движка роли не играет. Из игр, предположительно 2D аркады, казуалки. Должна быть возможность показа рекламы, поддержка мультиплеера и интеграции с Game Center (iOS) / OpenFeint, шаринг в соц сети. Доступ к Native API будет большим плюсом. Большое количество 3rd Party Tools, плагинов и наработок, ускоряющих процесс разработки тоже крайне желательно.

На данный момент есть два претендента: [Corona SDK](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/) и [Unity 3d](http://unity3d.com/). У обоих есть как плюсы так и минусы. Слышал разработка 2D игр на Unity требует довольно больших усилий, за то в замен получаем desktop и web версии!

В общем дискас. Плюсы, минусы, подводные камни. Возможно есть еще годные аналоги которые я упустил.

Comment: дельту добавь, может есть кто из бета-тестеров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Остановился на [Corona SDK,](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/) быстро, удобно. Код пишется на `Lua`, поддерживаютсю платформы `iOS` / `Android` / `Kindle Fire` / `Nook` и совсем скоро будет поддержка десктопных `Mac App Store` приложений.
В качестве редактора можно использовать `TextMate`, `Sublime Text 2`, `Intellij IDEA`, `VIM`. Для них всех есть бандлы добавляющие поддержку короны. Я пока остановился на `ST2`.

Большой плюс Короны, это очень много уроков, примеров кода и библиотек, а так же сторонних программ, типа `LevelBuilder`, `PhysicsHelper`, значительно упрощающих разработку.

Вот еще пару ссылок на туториалы:

- [Официальные семплы](http://developer.anscamobile.com/samples)
- [Mobile.Tuts+](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/corona/)
- [Learning Corona](http://www.learningcorona.com/) – вообще мега сайт, собраны почти все толковые уроки, что есть в сети.

Comment: Спустя 9 месяцев разработки, пожалуй напишу свои выводы:

Corona — отличный движок для простых 2D игрушек, идеально подходит для интерактивных книг и детских приложений. Но при разработке более серьезных игр столкнулись с множеством проблем: плохая производительность на некоторых Android устройствах, закрытый движок не позволяет встраивать сторонние бибилиотеки (большие проблемы с СДК издателей), фиксы некоторых критичных багов можно ждать по пол года.

В общем перешли на Unity3D.

Answer (score 4):

Я конечно в этом деле не спец, но могу сказать что часто вижу как используются движки типа Unity 3D и Box2D, последний используется во флэше тоже. Box2D бесплатен и довольно таки хорош.

**UPD:** Не малое количество всяких туториалов по движкам есть [тут.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/)

Comment: Спасибо, но там в основном все материалы по Cocos2D, опыт показал, что он не особо продуктивен, т.к. приходится писать кучу лишнего кода.

Comment: Хоть там материал только по кокосу, но все же есть много полезной инфы для iPhone-разраба в целом. Спасибо.

Comment: Вот тут еще полазил по своим закладкам и нашол еще один движок под названием SIO/SIO 2. http://sio2interactive.com/index.php Он не так дорого как Юнити 3Д, но сам предоставляет большое количество возможностей как для начальной ступени можно было бы взять его. Да и не забываем что SIO/SIO 2 является кроссплатформенным!

Comment: Ну как бы в поддержание "беседы" хотелось бы добавить еще один сайт http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/  Вот тут стоит поискать высказывания насчет движков, а именно можно заглянуть сюда http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4677/commercial-2d-game-engines

Comment: Ну как бы еще http://www.libsdl.org/